# How do I hide Administrative Tools on Windows Server 2008 R2 using group-policy?

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, terminal-server

We're locking down our terminal server machine for remote desktop users and can't seem to find how to hide Administrative Tools from the Start Menu for remote desktop users.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

two ways i can see

http://www.brianmadden.com/forums/t/19270.aspx

> Open the GPO in gpedit.msc and go to:
>
> User Config\Administrative
>   Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft
>   Management Console\ and restrict
>   access to author mode and any MMC snap
>   ins you don't want them to get to.
>
> Be sure that the computer side is in
>   loopback mode if you don't already
>   have a policy on your TS OU that does
>   this:
>
> Computer Config\Administrative
>   Templates\System\Group Policy\User
>   Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode
>   = enabled.
>
> Once the policy is created, it is a
>   good idea to deny apply rights to the
>   administrative staff that supports the
>   server.

OR

the way i do it is to redirect the start menu for all my terminal servers to another location e.g. \SERVER1\USERS\STARTMENU

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785925(WS.10).aspx

> Redirecting the Start Menu folder
>
> Folder Redirection of the Start Menu
>   folder is available in Windows XP,
>   Windows XP 64-Bit Edition, or Windows
>   Server 2003 operating systems. Start
>   Menu redirection is treated
>   differently from other redirected
>   folders in that the contents of the
>   user’s Start Menu are not copied to
>   the redirected location. It is assumed
>   that a redirected Start Menu has been
>   previously created by an administrator
>   and that all users share the same
>   Start Menu. As a best practice for
>   Windows XP–based computers, do not use
>   Folder Redirection to redirect the
>   Start Menu folder; instead, use Group
>   Policy to control what appears on the
>   Start Menu.